# std::length_error at memory location but no strings used

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the Unhandled exception: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location.

I have the following two constructor instances for the same class:

```
   Extract Cam1Extractor(c1getFrame);

   Extract Cam2Extractor(c2getFrame);
```

When in debug mode the first on is created without problem but the second one throws the exception above.

The constructor is as follows:

```
Extract::Extract(IplImage* inputImage)
{ 
     imageSize=cvGetSize(inputImage);

     original=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,inputImage->nChannels);//4
     cvCopy(inputImage,original);
     temp1=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,1);
     temp2=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,1);
     tmpBinary = cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,1);
     tmpOrig = cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,inputImage->nChannels);//4
     filteredImage=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,1);
     originalID=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,inputImage->nChannels);//4
     fr=cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8,inputImage->nChannels);//4
     numB=0;
}
```

When I step into the constructor above to locate the exception, it doent even begin to perform what is inside,breaking instantly at the opening bracket. I assume there is a problem allocating the memory for the pointer c2getFrame which is an image pointer (openCV's IplImage*).

The strange thing is that it runs fine in release mode!?!

Any ideas greatly appreciated. all the best,

Will

Comment: There's no way to answer this without seeing more of the code. Bear in mind that anything can throw a length_error; not necessarily just the standard classes.

Comment: Maybe try running it under the debugger and see where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: I have now added additional code. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Most likely the image is too big to be allocated, or the size is negative (e.g. because it failed to grab / load). Can you see what are the parameters of `c2getFrame` and which line in `Extract()` throws the exception?